# Converting 4-20mA to 0-5V to 3.3V

Tags: analog, impedance

I have a pressure transmitter that I supply 12VDC to which outputs a 4-20mA signal.  The circuit is based on an example in the [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/rcv420.pdf?ts=1630805115736) (figure1, page5).
[image: circuit]
The problem is I now need to take this analog signal (0-5VDC) to 0-3.3VDC.  So I imagine I should use a voltage divider but level translator is also an option?  I have more than one sensor reading I am taking to 3.3V from 5V but I am just wondering which will do the job better, and by this I mean will not downgrade the resolution of my analog signal?

Also how does one go about selecting the resistance values for the voltage divider?  I understand that I could use say R1=510 and R2=330 where Vin is 5V and get about 3V out.  But one time I used this voltage divider after an op amp on a circuit and messed everything up.  I was told that it was possible to use a voltage divider after the op amp had I selected much higher resistance values.

[image: voltage divider equation]

Comment: a voltage divider would be appropriate. However, the input resistance of the evaluation circuit should also be taken into account.

Comment: What's the problem with a 160 ohm resistor, 20 mA would then give 3.2 V.

Comment: Everything you add downgrades the resolution of your analog signal. And a resistor divider will do this, too, because the resistors themselves have tolerances -- the worst case situation would yield an error 4 times larger than the resistor tolerances, themselves, for example. Nothing is perfect. You will also need to calibrate out where the 4 mA is at and the 20 mA is at... and depending on the design you may need to do this for each channel.

Comment: @Neil_UK I assume you mean putting a 160ohm resistor between the 4-20mA emitter and the 3.3V MCU and eliminating the RCV420JP IC?

Comment: Also I still would like to know if I were to do a voltage divider, how to select the resistors whilst considering impedance.